# Adding objects with defined operator doesn't work as I expect

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

The output is equal 20. Why the return value isn't 30?

```
class Myclass
{
public:
    int result;

    Myclass() { result = 10; }

    Myclass operator+ (Myclass& obj) {
        Myclass tempObj;
        tempObj.result += obj.result;
        return tempObj;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Myclass obj1, obj2, obj3;
    cout << (obj1 + obj2 + obj3).result;
}
```

If I correct understand, obj2 + obj3 return tempObj with result = 20. The next step is addition tempObj + obj1, that should return again tempObj but with result = 30.

Comment: Hint: where do you tell `tempObj` that is should be equal to some other object?

Comment: Tip: write out each call of the operator in separately scoped '{' code blocks '}' and check what goes on with tempObj..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the operator

```
Myclass operator+ (Myclass& obj) {
    Myclass tempObj;
    tempObj.result += obj.result;
    return tempObj;
}
```

there is created local object `tempObj` the data member `result` of which is always initialized by `10`.

So though the temporary object created by the sub-expression

```
obj1 + obj2
```

has the data member `result` is equal to `20` nevertheless its value is ignored.

It seems you mean

```
Myclass operator+ (Myclass& obj) {
    Myclass tempObj( *this );
    tempObj.result += obj.result;
    return tempObj;
}
```

Pay attention to that the parameter should have a constant reference type and the operator itself should be constant.  For example

```
Myclass operator+ ( const Myclass& obj) const {
    Myclass tempObj( *this );
    tempObj.result += obj.result;
    return tempObj;
}
```

Comment: The last one. Is it really necessary or it's just a good practice?

Comment: @VanQator It is really necessary. For example declare the first or last object as  const MyClass obj1, obj3;

Answer (score 1):

`operator+` is performed from left to right, then `obj1 + obj2 + obj3` is interpreted as `(obj1 + obj2) + obj3`, i.e. `obj1 + obj2` is performed firstly. The temporary object returned by `obj1 + obj2` contains `result` as `20`, then the `operator+` is performed with the temporary as the left operand, `obj3` as the right operand. In the `operator+`, the left operand (i.e. `*this`) is not used at all, it always performs addition on the local object `tempObj` (whose `result` is `10`) and the right operand (`obj3`'s `result` is `10` too), then you got the result `20`.

`operator+` should perform addition on both the left and right operands. e.g.

```
Myclass operator+ (Myclass& obj) {
    Myclass tempObj(*this);
    tempObj.result += obj.result;
    return tempObj;
}
```

or

```
Myclass operator+ (Myclass& obj) {
    Myclass tempObj;
    tempObj.result = this->result + obj.result;
    return tempObj;
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. In another words. Every time as defined operator is used, there's created a new tempObj on the left side (result = 10) and then it's added to the object on the right side which result also is equal 10. What i have to do is indicate, that I want add value of the returned object before (ob1 + obj2) , not a value from new tempObj. So, I have to use *this.